# Converting Excel Worksheets to DMN file

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am working with Camunda on decision rules. I have created an Excel sheet and I want to convert this sheet to a .dmn file so that I can use that .dmn file in Camunda modeler.

Please let me know how we can convert the Excel sheet into a .dmn file.

This is my sample Excel to make a decision table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I explored and got the below solution and its working for me.**

**Step 1:** [Download the command line tool](https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/camunda/bpm/extension/dmn/dmn-xlsx-cli/0.1.0/dmn-xlsx-cli-0.1.0.jar?_gl=1*3ss878*_ga*Njg1NjIwNDgxLjE2ODk1ODI3NTA.*_ga_4EYN8X5FNR*MTY4OTgyODYyNS40LjAuMTY4OTgyODYyNS42MC4wLjA.&_ga=2.78475604.1152997158.1689744088-685620481.1689582750). It is a runnable jar file. Extract the jar file and store it in a directory.

**Step 2:** Get the Excel file that you want to convert into a .dmn file and keep it in the same directory to the downloaded jar.

**Step 3:** Run the command `java -jar dmn-xlsx-cli-0.1.0.jar --inputs A,B,C --outputs D,E,F path/to/input/file.xlsx path/to/output/file.dmn`

**Notes:**

`A,B,C` are the Excel columns that you want to input in your`.dmn` file.

`D,E,F` are the output columns in your.DMN file.

And the `sheet name` will be your ID of the DMN file.

If your excel is long then it will take some times, so have paitient and enojoy your work.

Answer (score 1):

**I explored and got to know another solution:**

**By using the plugin:**

**Step 1: Clone this repo:**

(a): Goto plugin folder inside Camunda modeler

(b): Clone this repo in the plugin folder by the below command:

```
git clone https://github.com/pinussilvestrus/camunda-modeler-excel-import-plugin.git
```

(c): Go to the cloned directory by `cd camunda-modeler-excel-import-plugin`

(d): Install dependencies by `npm i`

(e): Run the plugin by `npm run all`

[image]

**Step 2: Open Camunda modeler UI**

**Step 3: You can see the import Excel sheet button**

[image]

**Step 4: Import the valid sheet and convert the sheet into Camunda DMN.**